# Visual Studio 2019 .cs file not found when referencing nuget package for Statsd

Tags: c#, nuget, statsd

I installed the **StatsdCsharpClient** package via NuGet. When I run my code via VS, I get  .cs file not found when referencing NuGet package for Statsd.cs Not found and another file and in the details it seems VS is looking for the files via and "F file share on in a GitHub folder. The process to log something to statsD never completes. Any help would be much appreciated. I've already tried adjusting some debugging settings and did a VS repair, which were suggestions I found on similar threads.

Comment: The method is depreciated.  There is a recommended replacement.  See : https://github.com/Pereingo/statsd-csharp-client

Comment: I'm using this one jdweng, https://github.com/lukevenediger/statsd-csharp-client not the depreciated one you mentioned. I appreciate the assistance and answer though. :)

Comment: Did you read the bottom of the link?  It says See Also statsd.  https://github.com/lukevenediger/statsd-csharp-client#readme